# How do you gag a fish-person without tape?

Tags: merfolk, vocalizations

The fish-people are hybrids of fish and humans: They have bodies akin to standard teleost fish, such as carp or salmon, with a face, brain, and throat like a human. While it would be quite easy to tape their mouths shut, the world doesn't have any tape: The technology level is around Medieval Europe. Tying a gag around their mouth seems to present some issues, such as the fact that they do not truly have a back of the head, and their body shape, form, and texture seem to make it impossible to use it for affixing gags

Given this, is there a way to gag a fish-person without the need for tape?

Comment: This is a hard one to make heads or tails of.  Are they speaking with air or water? If they have a larynx, does it lead to a lung/swim bladder capable of expelling air?  Even if they have nostrils that connect to the pharynx, it's hard to picture small openings passing enough water to allow life if the mouth is gagged.  I feel like a proper answer involves concealing the sound of [Fast Repetitive Ticks](https://www.science.org/content/article/farting-fish-keep-touch), something which humans strive to do on occasion also. :)

Comment: Just jam a wadded up towel/rag into their mouths.  This works for both humans and fish.

Comment: Tell them a bad joke.

Comment: What tape can be applied underwater anyways? Also, I don't think Medieval Europe had much tape tech, I think the closest they would have gotten is cloth.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Ball gag.**

[image: ball gag shark]

[https://www.amazon.com/Hog-Wild-Shark-Popper-Toy/dp/B00BIK3YFO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BIK3YFO)

The depicted shark can spit the balls out with a mighty HACKTHU!  Only rare ones among your fish people are capable of such expectoration, and these doughty fishfolk are deemed to have the right to say what they please.

Those fish people of lesser puissance must gnaw the foam ball while they consider what they will say once it is removed.

Answer (score 12):

## Getting your Hooks into it:

We're talking (talking) fish here. The head and neck are presumably semi-rigidly attached to the fish body covered in fish scales. Those fish-people have no fingers with which to undo things. So take a strip of cloth/hide (whatever) and put hooks of bone, wood, or metal in the material. Hook the hooks under the scales (as gently or cruelly as you like) and wrap the thing around the head. Secure the whole thing tightly to the other side's scales.

[image]

**It wouldn't need to be QUITE as gruesome as that sounds.** A special [flat hook](https://www.kinedyne.com/which-end-fitting-is-right-for-the-job-/c/4693) could be designed to fit under scales, and a strap fitted over the mouth with either bungee-type material or some kind of cinch. Still not fun.

[image]

A ball gag will work very similarly, secured to the scales or gills on either side. If they can breathe through gills, then a leather bag wrapped around the head and cinched tightly will both gag and blind the fish-people, since they have a narrower neck. A ball gag secured around the neck with a [bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_(horse)#:%7E:text=A%20bit%20consists%20of%20two,the%20bridle%20and%20reins%20attach.) and bridle assembly set up like on a horse will leave the nose free  for breathing and still avoid hooks under scales if a gentler arrangement is desired. It would be more complicated and it would still be quite unpleasant for a fish-person to wear.

[image] [image]

If they have gills, no problem, they can breathe. If they breathe air, then you'll need to leave the nose free (wet cloth is really hard to breathe through). If you're trying to keep them from screaming, I'll assume they breathe (or at least CAN) air.

We're not being nice here, but it could be worse. You could sew their mouth shut with string and a needle, or simply with a bunch of fish hooks. If the tongue is an issue, stab through the tongue and out the bottom of the jaw and secure it to the bottom of the mouth. I've seen worse done to actual fish.

And for an especially gruesome alternative, there is always the [tongue-eating louse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cymothoa_exigua), that could be inserted into their mouth. It necrotizes a fish's tongue and then feeds off part of the fish's blood, mucus, or food. That's a bit more permanent than I suspect you want.

[image]

Comment: Well you could just put the hooks in the mouth like a normal fish.

Comment: @DKNguyen That was in the paragraph one up from the last, as one of the more brutal options (along with sewing the mouth shut).

Comment: +1 for the louse, the OP should develop (magic/selective breeding) a creature that likes to latch onto their enemy's mouth

Comment: While probably not a good option unless the sub's bald shouldn't a number of tight loops around the head top to bottom (to hold the jaw shut and front to back prevent it from being easily defeated like the silly single strip over the lips that's strictly aesthetic/voluntary in effect?

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight That might be helpful. but you still need the strip across the face. you can speak surprisingly loudly with your jaw shut but your lips open. But combined with something like a rag stuffed in the mouth, it would work. There are a lot of way available, certainly.

Answer (score 5):

## Porcupine fish

[image: A puffed porcupine fish]

1. Dope a spiny puffer fish
2. Put the puffer inside Sammy the Salmon's mouth
3. Get some coffe in there to wake your spiked friend up.
4. ???
5. Profit!

The puffer will be puffed until he chills, so to keep this going just poke him every once in a while until you and your humanoid fish friend are done making love.

Comment: Ouch! A little damaging, don't you think? Still, it's an underpants gnomes reference...

Comment: @DWKraus it hurts less if they don't move their mouth. Depending in the puffer's size it won't hurt if the fishperson doesn't resist.

Comment: Also there's the risk of tetrodotoxins.  The spines may be the *least* dangerous part of the puffer fish.  Putting that in someone's *mouth* can be quite hazardous.  (Master sushi chefs train for years to extract the one tiny part of that fish that isn't poisonous.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman that's dangerous to humans, but dolphins tap that to get high on purpose. Only the OP knows what it'll do to their fish people.

Answer (score 5):

#### Assumption challenge: have you tried using tape?

Like many people in the kink community, I have.

Anyone who's actually tried it finds out immediately that tape over the mouth doesn't work as a gag. Unless you superglue the tape to the lips, anyone (even a child) can immediately remove any amount of tape over their lips simply by opening their mouth. It simply doesn't stick that well.

Even other gags like ball gags and bit gags don't really work as-is. It doesn't take much work with teeth and lips to get them out, even if they're done up tight. There's always some stretch in straps and in your skin and muscles.

There are only two ways to ensure a gag stays in.

- Make the insertable element long enough that however much anything stretches or moves, it can't come out. This is the principle behind the tongue depressor in a scold's bridle.
- Mount the head-securing structure securely enough that there's very little movement possible.

This is true for horses, for kink enthusiasts who really want to be gagged properly, and of course it's going to be equally true for your fish people.

Exactly how this would be mounted on a fish person's head of course would completely depend on what shape their head is, whether they have a neck, whether they have fins which could be used as securing points, or potentially even whether they have parts of their skin or body which aren't very sensitive and could have hooks put through. We'd need much more anatomical detail to say exactly.

Answer (score 2):

**Anchor at the gills**

[image]

The purple part goes around the snout to stop the fish speaking. The red part is a wedge that goes through the gill into the back of the mouth. There is another red thing at the other side of the fish. Both red things are attached to the snout by ropes. Once tightened it cannot be removed.

This would be even more secure if the fish has more than one gill slit on each side of the head. Just anchor to the strip of flesh between slits

Comment: This kind of attachment has killed every fish I've ever seen it done to. Anything with gills seems real easy to kill fish with. But I agree it's a great spot to attach things.

Comment: @DWKraus Dang, I thought I had invented something new.